# How ADCO/TOPO "Propagated State Vector" should be interpreted?

Tags: iss, position

Here https://github.com/ISS-Mimic/Mimic I read: "The current total epic and all inclusive list of public **telemetry** can be seen at our page here [https://iss-mimic.github.io/Mimic/"](https://iss-mimic.github.io/Mimic/%22).

The list includes: "US Guidance, Navigation and Control (GNC) J2000 **Propagated** State Vector" whose timestamp is 40 seconds in the past.

Are those values ​​coming from telemetry or are they propagated?

Comment: Could be both, if it's the onboard vector.

Comment: @OrganicMarble please, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The ISS onboard GNC system propagates its own state vector. If that gets sent down to the ground, it's telemetry. See page 125 in https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf